# Smartcard System Supporting RSA Encryption

Tags: encryption, rsa, digital-signature, sha1, smartcard

Is there any smartcard system capable of performing [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) encryption?
The purpose is to create [digital signatures](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Digital_Signature_diagram.svg/1024px-Digital_Signature_diagram.svg.png) (e.g. based on [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha-1) hashes) of arbitrary binary data without exposing the private key.

Signature verification would be nice to have but is not required as the verification is performed by a distinct system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create digital signatures signing is used (not encryption). Most hardware (both smartcards and USB tokens) which can hold private keys will also perform cryptographic operations with those keys without revealing them -- that's the core purpose of this hardware.

Comment: That's true. However as you can see from the picture the signature is defined as an encrypted hash. Of course it would be best to send the arbitrary data to the smartcard and it just spits out the signature. At a minimum the smartcard should perform the encryption while keeping the private key hidden and bound to a physical piece of hardware which can be locked away in a safe. It's similar to Microsoft Autheticode for executables but I haven't seen any such system for arbitrary data yet such as custom executable formats for embedded hardware. Seems there is no such thing that's widely used.

Comment: @mibollma the picture is misleading. DSA (I know you were asking about RSA) can't be used for encryption, but works for signing. Now about the smartcards - as I wrote most smartcards which can hold the private keys can also sign the hash (they don't process large data blocks because their computational power is too low). You should look for smartcards which support PKCS#11 interface. Finally if you need just some hardware device, there's a wide variety of USB cryptotokens which don't require smartcard readers and can do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @mibollma -1 for the question is not mine (just in case).

Comment: Thanks for those tips. That helps alot. The downrating is a bit weird. Whatever...

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene told, that's the key point of smart cards; the optimum scenario in respect to key confidentiality is,  that the key is generated on the card itself and so never needs to leave it. Note that **encryption** would involve the **public** key,  while for a **digital signature** obviously the **private** key is required. It is also important to consider, that the I/O bandwith of smart cards is restricted. A typical approach is due to performance reasons, to hash outside the card - either completely or upto the last block of text to be signed, especially if large amounts of data need to be signed.

Comment: So you are saying the picture on the right is plain wrong? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature

Comment: @mibollma: Yes, both pictures are not quite exact in respect to "encrypt" and "decrypt" in the bold arrows showing the key symbol. (Note, that in RSA context a different padding would be applied for signatures than for en-/decryption so the term is misleading too). At least the correct key is mentioned in both cases. :)